# How do we not stringify a json while encoding data using swift encodable?

Tags: json, swift, encoding, codable

I have struct to make request models

```
struct SignUpRequestModel:Encodable {

    let firstName:String
    let lastName:String
    let email:String
    let password:String
    let nickName:String
    let platform = "ios"
    let fcmId:String

    //Optional params
    let referalCode:String
    let facebookId:String
    let googleId:String
    let fcmUserId:String
    let image:String

}
```

This is the model initialised

```
 let requestModel = SignUpRequestModel(firstName: "Sooraj", lastName: "Jeesson", email: "althafe@******.com", password: "123456", nickName: "Sooraj", fcmId: "**********", referalCode: "", facebookId: "", googleId: "", fcmUserId: "", image: "")
```

The output of the following will be stringified

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.keyEncodingStrategy = .convertToSnakeCase
let encodedData = try encoder.encode(requestModel)

ex - "{\n  \"facebook_id\" : \"\",\n  \"nick_name\" : \"Sooraj\",\n  \"google_id\" : \"\",\n  \"password\" : \"123456\",\n  \"platform\" : \"ios\",\n  \"image\" : \"\",\n  \"first_name\" : \"Sooraj\",\n  \"fcm_id\" : \"**********\",\n \"last_name\" : \"Jeesson\",\n  \"email\" : \"althafe@*******.com\",\n  \"referal_code\" : \"\",\n  \"fcm_user_id\" : \"\"\n}"
```

How do we not stringify(The `"` beore and after `{` `}` of json object) a data while encoding using JSONEncoder. I wanted to pass this as a JSON only to my server. I tried some solutions but doesn't seem to work . My backend doesn't accept stringified json as the android version is already deployed and live.

This is the output in server

```
[Object: null prototype] {
'{"facebook_id":"","nick_name":"sooraj","google_id":"","password":"123456","platform":"ios","image":"","first_name":"sooraj","fcm_id":"bvcxfrty5634tgerbfcvndfgdfgbvbdgsvbgtujyiyui675634trfsdfdszgvcvx","last_name":"jeesson","email":"althafe@newagesmb.com","referal_code":"","fcm_user_id":""}': '' }
```

I am using alamofire to make request. The encoded data is passed like this

```
 //MARK:Make the request body
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = method.rawValue
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        if requestData != nil{
            request.httpBody = requestData!
        }
```

The alamofire encoding type is default.. i have not made any changes there

Comment: I don't see the issue. What did you print exactly? Put it in a `UILabel` (or equivalent), I think you are misinterpreting debug output addon

Comment: The JSON itself shouldn't be stringified. It only seems stringified because you are looking at it through a debugger or something similar. Can you print, from your server, the JSON that your server received?

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: JSON **is** a string by definition. If the server expects a dictionary send a dictionary. And never *prettyPrint* the string. The server doesn’t care.

Comment: Thank you @ vadian.. This was my issue.. I should have send a dict. The keys are snake cased when send to server which is why i prefered encodable. I was able to perform the function after making the encoded data to a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

the `Content-Type` should be `application/json`